# What's the best car for exploring, both on and off-road?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

I want a car that can climb a mountain or cross a small stream but can also travel the roads at a relatively high speed and get me across the map fast.

I would like it if it has some armor and not take damage easily so I can do fun jumps and tricks while driving along. I also want to be able to store this vehicle in my garage and modify it to my liking.

Is there a car that will suit all these purposes?

Comment: I'm thinking the Mesa, would that work for what I need or us there something better?

Answer (score 2):

Try the Dubsta 6x6. It's fast if you fully upgrade it and also it's got 6 wheel drive so it's brilliant off road! Also, it's got high suspension which means you can get through your rivers!

[image: Here's a picture of it]

Tip: when upgrading it DO NOT lower the suspension. It will ruin it's off road capability.

Comment: Thanks, I've driven it before and really enjoyed the ride, I'm going to save up for one on online as well now.